# sql replace all characters between two strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to figure out a way to update / replace only text between two strings.

For instance I need to be able to update the field and replace only what's in between the following script tags leaving the text before the opening script tag untouched.

```
I want to keep this string<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">********</script>
```

I suppose REPLACE is not going to work as the text in between the script tags will vary. Is there some type of wildcard?

```
UPDATE Products_Joined 
SET TechSpecs = REPLACE (CAST(TechSpecs AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">********</script>', '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">new text</script>' )
```

UPDATED: with @Parkyprg answer This works but doesn't replace the closing `</script>` tag.
I end up with this.

```
I want to keep this string new text</script>
```

How do we remove the closing script tag as well?

```
UPDATE Products_Joined
SET TechSpecs = REPLACE(CAST(TechSpecs AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
SUBSTRING(CAST(TechSpecs AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
CHARINDEX('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">',TechSpecs),
CHARINDEX('</script>',CAST(TechSpecs AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) - 
CHARINDEX('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">',TechSpecs)
),' new text')
```

Comment: Check [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/xpregex.aspx).

Comment: How does `nvarchar(max)` in your code correlate with the `sql-server-2000` tag that your question's got? SQL Server 2000 doesn't support the `max` size specifier for strings.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't 2000, not sure really.

Comment: @user357034 - You can use `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out. For future questions best to say the correct version as 2000 has lots of limitations compared to 2005 and 2008 so you may well get sub optimal answers.

Comment: hmm, tried that but it returned nothing, no error either.

Comment: @user357034 - OK. Well you must be on at least 2005 as `nvarchar(max)` works. If you execute `DECLARE @I INT = 1` do you get an error? If not you are on 2008. 2005 would give you the error `Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.`

Comment: Running that I do get "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @OpenTag varchar(100)
SET @OpenTag = '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">'

UPDATE Products_Joined
SET TechSpecs  = STUFF(TechSpecs ,
                       CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, TechSpecs ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag),
                            CHARINDEX('</script>',TechSpecs ,1)-(CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, TechSpecs ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag)), 
                       'New Text')
```

Comment: This won't run on SQL Server 2000

Comment: @user357034 - Yes. That goes back to Sybase days. Define "Not working". You get an error? It doesn't update anything? Works fine for me.

Comment: "Derived table 'derived' is not updatable because a column of the derived table is derived or constant." on SQL Server 2000

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Ah thanks. Will just abandon the derived table and inline everything then. Was only there to avoid repeating the expression. I notice the OP references `nvarchar(max)` in the question though anyway(!?)

Comment: Your edit works perfect. Just needed to cast the TechSpecs like this CAST(TechSpecs AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) and it worked great.

Comment: @user357034 - So this is not SQL Server 2000 but the data type is `text`?

Comment: Really not sure, limited knowledge, VARCHAR(MAX)) works as well

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the best solution, but...

```
UPDATE Products_Joined
SET TechSpecs = REPLACE(TechSpecs, 
SUBSTRING(TechSpecs,
  CHARINDEX('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">',TechSpecs),
  CHARINDEX('</script>',TechSpecs) - 
  CHARINDEX('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">',TechSpecs)
)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: You need to add in what is being replaced - at the moment, the REPLACE function only takes two arguments and is missing a `)`.

Comment: Ok this kinda works with a little modification but doesn't replace the closing </script> tag